# JavaScript scope with calling functions of the same class

Tags: javascript, scope

It works fine as the following:

```
function A() {
}

A.prototype.f1 = function() {
  alert('f1');
};

A.prototype.f2 = function() {
  // calls f1
  A.prototype.f1();
};

var a = new A();
a.f2(); // alert f1 correctly
```

But there's a function B to make A undefined to window scope, but can be accessed inside B scope:

```
function A() {
}

A.prototype.f1 = function() {
  alert('f1');
};

A.prototype.f2 = function() {
  // calls f1
  A.prototype.f1();
};

function B() {
  var PrivateA = null;

  this.makePrivate = function() {
    PrivateA = A;     // private access
    A = undefined;        // undefined with window object
  };

  this.callA = function() {
    var a = new PrivateA();
    a.f2();               // it calls A.prototype.f1();, but A is undefined now
  };
}

var b = new B();
// expect to accessible
var a = new A();

b.makePrivate();
// expect to inaccessible to window
alert(typeof A);         // expect to be 'undefined'
b.callA();               // expect to alert 'f1', which not works now since A is undefined
```

I want make A accessible before B is called and A inaccessible when B is called.

Please give some advice.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the second and third lines in your `B` function?

Comment: @Blender I know that works, but that is not I want. I have updated the code and show what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up `B` to look like this:

```
function B() {
    var PrivateA;  // It's not accessible from outside of B's scope

    this.makePrivate = function() {
        PrivateA = A;  // Still in B's scope, so it works
        A = undefined;
    };

    this.callA = function() {
        var a = new PrivateA();  // So is this
        a.f2();
    };
}
```

Here's what happens when I run it:

```
> var b = new B();
> A
function A() {
    this.f1 = function() {
        alert('f1');
    };

    this.f2 = function() {
        // calls f1
        this.f1();
    };
}
> b.makePrivate();
> A
undefined
> b.callA();  // I get an alert that says 'f1'
```

Comment: I noticed you got 'f1' because you changed f1 and f2 into A. But I want to make them inside A.prototype.

Comment: @Ovilia: You can extend `A`'s prototype, but you can't use `A.prototype.f1();` (why don't you just write `this.f1()`?).

Comment: Because A is in a file that I can't change.

Comment: @Ovilia: Not much you can do then.